# how to translalte option in redux framework with wpml or another plugins wordpress?

Tags: r, wordpress

i have a site with two languages.

```
 i'm using w.p.m.l plugins to translate all thing. 
            but, when i show the panel of this r.e.d.u.x  framework
            I can't translate option in input (text), text area (editor) ...etc. 
            something like title, description is o.k, it's can be translate by (p o) file.

how to translate the option in r.e.d.u.x  framework to view in
front-end with greater than 1 language
```

i can't write r.e.d.u.x framework normally, i got some err,

help me.

Comment: The folks over at WPML give excellent support and service. So, I'd always recommend you go via them. Is it the values entered into your REDUS Framework options or the labels and descriptions that you need to translate?

Comment: i want translate the value of redux framework. @Phil healey.
when after setup wpml, enter option are not string or button switch to translate to another languages....